# How does installing a new operating system impacts the Dates Created and Modified of its files?

Tags: file, date

When I power on a computer, load the operating system, and create my user account, all for the first time, what the timestamps of the "Date created" and "Date modified" to be like?

Obviously the files were created and packed before I purchased the computer, but I want to know if the files' Date Created equal the time when I first load the operating system and create the first account?

Or Perhaps the created date equals the true creation time when engineers developed the software, and the file's Date modified equals the date in which these are unpacked for end user?

In short, I want to understand how/if the timing of my unpacking a new computer with a fresh operating system impacts the files within.

Comment: The internal file dates won't change, but if you set the local time zone for your new OS differently than your old OS, files will *appear* to change their dates.

Comment: @MarkLavin thank you. What do you mean by "won't change." What date won't change? and that date that won't change, what set it? An installation? the creation time by engineers?

Comment: I believe that the date/times of files -- creation, last update, last access -- are represented as "epoch times", the number of seconds/milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT.   The dates you see, e.g., when you list files, are the result of translating those epoch times into timezone-specific local times, depending on what you set as the OS's local time zone.